# Whether or not SQL query (SELECT) continues or stops reading data from table when find the value

Tags: mysql, sql

Greeting,
My question; Whether or no sql query (SELECT) **continues or stops reading data (records) from table when find the value** that I was looking for?

referance: "In order to return data for this query, mysql must start at the beginning of the disk data file, read in enough of the record to know where the category field data starts (because long_text is variable length), read this value, see if it satisfies the where condition (and so decide whether to add to the return record set), then figure out where the next record set is, then repeat."

link for referance: http://www.verynoisy.com/sql-indexing-dummies/#how_the_database_finds_records_normally

Comment: It depends on the index type and the query/data.

Comment: What do you mean `the value you were looking for`? How do *you* know there isn't another record that matches the same criteria on the next page? Unless there are indexes and statistics that the database can use, it has no option but to do a full table scan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it scans the entire file. Unless you put something like

```
select * from user where id=100 limit 1
```

This of course will still search entire rows if id 100 is the last record.

If id is a primary key it will automatically be indexed and searching would be optimized

Comment: This assumes that there is only one value with id equal to 100. Unless there is a unique constraint on the columns, neither the database nor you know that the correct result was found. `LIMIT 1` will return the wrong result if there are more than one row with that id

Comment: this assumes primary keys are always indexed which might not be the case. I found in several instances that you can get a huge performance increase if you define an index on primary key.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I did not say it will return the right result. but it will stop at the first occurrence that satisfies the query which is what the question is about

Comment: @TuncayGöncüoğlu I dont know which dbms you are using but at least for mysql, primary keys are ALWAYS automatically indexed.

Answer (score 2):

In general you don't know and you don't care, but you have to adapt when queries take too long to execute. When you do something like

```
select a,b,c from mytable where a=3 and b=5
```

then the database engine has a couple of options to optimize. When all these options fail, then it will do a "full table scan" - which means, it will have to examine the entire table to see which rows are eligible. When you have indices on e.g. column `a` then the database engine can optimize the search because it can pre-select rows where `a` has value 3. So, in general, make sure that you have indices for the columns that are most searched. (Perversely, some database engines get confused when you have too many indices and will fall back to a full table scan because they've lost their way...)

As to whether or not the scanning stops: In general, the database engine has to examine all data in the table (hopefully aided by indices) and won't stop after having found just one hit. If you want just the first hit, use a `limit 1` clause to make sure that your result set has only one outcome. But then again, if you have a `sort by` clause, the database engine cannot stop after the first hit, there might be next ones that should get priority given the sorting.

Summarizing, how the db engine does its scan depends on how smart it is, what indices are available etc.. If your `select` queries take too long then consider re-organizing your indices, writing your `select` statements differently, or rebuilding the table.

Comment: Karel Kubat your ansewr is good. To me is most interested. 
I am most interested because optimization database and sql query...

Comment: How I know, the database engine most read all data in order to get data what I looking for - in most case.

Answer (score 2):

The RDBMS **reading data from disk** is something you cannot know, you should not care and you must not rely on.

The issue is too broad to get a precise answer. The engine reads data from storage in blocks, a block can contain records that are not needed by the query at hand. If all the columns needed by the query is available in an index, the RDBMS won't even read the data file, it will only use the index. The data it needs could already be cached in memory (because it was read during the execution of a previous query). The underlying OS and the storage media also keep their own caches.

On a busy system, all these factors could lead to very different storage access patterns while running the same query several times on a couple of minutes apart.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry... I thought the table.

I will change question and I will explain it in the following image;
[image: picture table explain]

I understand that in CASE 1 all columns must be read with each iteration.
My question is: If it's the same in the CASE 2 or columns that are not selected in the query are excluded from reading in each iteration.

Also, are the both queries are the some in performance perspective?

Clarify:

CASE: 1  In first CASE select print all data
CASE: 2 In second CASE select print columns first_name and last_name

Whether in CASE 2 mysql server (SQL query) reads only columns first_name, last_name or read the entire table to get that data(rows)=(first_name, last_name)?

An interest of me how the server reads table row in CASE 1 and CASE 2?